# Help identifying pwm controller "67A"

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, identification, surface-mount

I am repairing a battery charger that uses two power supplies. TH20594 (couldn't find any info on that either) controls the primary PSU, while the mysterious chip controls the bootstrap/standby supply (aux winding on the smaller transformer provides power to the TH20594). It does not work, but I cannot find any information about the chip.

The chip is a really small 6 pin SMD package (TSSOP-6?) and is marked as "67A".

[Here](http://radiokot.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1051644&sid=36a2b98c51d1cf9c8ae6f3b1a051afb5#p1051644) is part of the schematic of a power supply (cannot guarantee the accuracy though).

Anyone knows what chip it is and where to find a datasheet for it (as well as the TH20594)?

67A:
[image]

TH20594:
[image]

EDIT: It is definitely "67A".

Comment: Picture is required. Might not be tssop. It's rarely smaller than 8 pins.

Comment: @Passerby The request is specifically for _repairing_ a commercial product, not to design a new circuit or even to develop a detailed understanding of an existing circuit. I voted to close because "Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired."

Comment: @JoeHass They have identified the surrounding circuit, and understand what part of the PSU the chips control, as well as a good schematic at the link. That sounds like demonstrating a good understanding of the underlying design. And they arn't asking "this thing is broke, how do I fix it" They are asking and I literally quote "Anyone knows what chip it is and where to find a datasheet for it (as well as the TH20594)". FFS.

Comment: @Passerby, thanks for the edit. Yea, I am not looking for an advice on how to fix it, but rather information about the two chips.

Comment: I have the same board of a Metabo ASC30-36 charger without any reaction. After the bridge rectifier I measure about 320V. Have you already found a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the TH20594:
I can find references (in russian), [here](http://therepair.ru/topic/2887-zariadnoe-metabo-asc-30/)  that states the TH20594MC1.4 is a PWM controller, which makes sense in this context.

I can't read russian (I used google translate) but it seems to indicate that there are similar replacement parts with different numbers, perhaps clones by different manufacturers, e.g. TI UC3845.  Tracing out some of the components and comparing with a typical PWM control IC might give evidence to this possibility.

You can find sources for the TH20594MC1.4 in lots of places in China, but I could not find any datasheet (and it would be probably in Chinese anyway, perhaps why a doc search fails)

For the '67A':
The closest I can find that matches is a 67(space)A, where A is the date code.  This is an ON semi quad TVS diode, NUP4302MR6. Which given the product I doubt is correct, but perhaps I bit of probing with a DVM might yield more info to verify (negatively or positively) this.

I would better guess that given product and the sorts of components around it, it's an opamp or comparator.

Sorry for the incomplete answer, it's not possible to put a so much text in a comment.
Can give more info, e.g. Trace out the circuit and measure resistance between pins (in both directions).

Comment: I have posted a link to part of the circuit (hot side only) in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 9 YEARS later, but it might help someone, as I have a power supply in which the same IC went bad. 
The IC in question is an SMPS controller MLX02367A made by Melexis. 
No datasheet or more information is available from the manufacturer who says it was a special design ASIC for which they don't give out datasheets or info. 
However, one person has drawn a simple schematic from a small SMPS in which it had failed. 
Here is that schematic (from https://jestineyong.com/blown-up-5-volt-usb-charger-repaired/):
[image: SMD IC 67A or Melexis MLX02367A]

So, obviously it's a flyback SMPS controller and its pin functions can be relatively easily guessed:

1. Vcc or positive supply (also connected to HV+ or positive high voltage through a large value resistor)
2. Switching transistor driver output
3. Ground, 0 or negative supply
4. Frequency setting or compensation
5. Possibly Vref (voltage reference)
6. Current sense or feedback

This IC can be purchased in bulk at low prices from AliExpress, typically at less than $3 for 10 pieces (there are multiple sellers for it). I already got a few of them and I'm about to install it and see how it works. I will report on whether it was successful and the measured voltage on the supply and reference pins.

Answer (score -2):

Chip 67A= SG6848 or LD7550
Low Cost Green-Mode PWM Controller for Flyback Converters

Comment: Reason for this conclusion? Supporting evidence?

Comment: Some more detail would possibly turn this into an excellent answer, please consider adding to it.

Comment: Sorry....but
the 67A is not pin compatible with the SG6848 and LD7550. 67A pin 3 or 6 (difficult to find pin 1) is the ground. pin 1 or 4 is the Vcc pin 2 or 5 is the OUT pin 6 or 3 s the sense other pins seem to have different functions of the others.